# how to make undertow work as a reverse proxy to a bunch of internal applications

Tags: java, undertow

I want to reverse proxy a bunch of different internal applications using [Undertow](http://undertow.io/).

For example my applications are:

- secure.stage.org/application1/index.jsp
- cee.stage.org/application1/default.aspx

Every request to these applications should go through the proxy server - The proxy server in turn sets the authentication token on these requests and fulfils the request, the response is sent back to the client browser without exposing the authentication token.

I am not sure how to implement this in undertow? Not sure if it is possible using undertow webserver.

Comment: There is a pretty straightforward example on the official undertow repository:
https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/io/undertow/examples/reverseproxy/ReverseProxyServer.java
You can wrap the proxy handler into a handler that will take care of your authentication needs